# How can I log the stdout of a process started by start-stop-daemon?

Tags: logging, stdout, init.d, start-stop-daemon

I am using an init script to run a simple process, which is started with:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER    \
    --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --background       \
    --exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS
```

The process called $DAEMON usually prints log information to its standard output.  As far as I can tell this data is not being stored anywhere.

I would like to write or append the stdout of $DAEMON to a file somewhere.

The only solution I know is to tell start-stop-daemon to call a shellscript instead of $DAEMON directly; the script then calls $DAEMON and writes to the logfile.  But that requires an extra script which, like modifying the daemon itself, seems the wrong way to solve such a common task.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

To expand on ypocat's answer, since it won't let me comment:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER    \
 --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --background       \
 --startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS > /var/log/some.log 2>&1"
```

Using `exec` to run the daemon allows stop to correctly stop the child process instead of just the bash parent.

Using `--startas` instead of `--exec` ensures that the process will be correctly detected by its pid and won't erroneously start multiple instances of the daemon if start is called multiple times. Otherwise, start-stop-daemon will look for a /bin/bash process and ignore the actual child process running the daemon.

Comment: This is a far better solution than the one of @ypocat mainly because shutting the daemon down again by replacing `--start` with `--stop` actually works.

Comment: I tried running this command from rc.local instead of init.d... I dont seem to be getting the same results. However when running it from a shell through SSH it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks mate! Now the pidfile refers to the daemon process itselt, not the Bash parent process!

Comment: How would the accompanying `start-stop-daemon --test (...)` look like?

Comment: Does this overwrite the file `/var/log/some.log` or append to it?

Comment: @stormbeta you're using --chuid and -c in the same command. is that right?
also, if how can i make sure the process is run as a non root user? this command only runs the process as root

Comment: brilliant, your method enlightened me.

Comment: @MattClimbs It overwrites the file after every start. use `>>` instead of `>` for appending.

Comment: Before you freak out (like me) because your log was empty, be aware this is buffered! You can use "exec stdbuf -oL -eL $DAEMON $DAEMONARGS > $LOGFILE 2>&1" to force the output to flush each line (from https://blog.lanyonm.org/articles/2015/01/11/raspberry-pi-init-script-python.html )

Answer (score 49):

You need to do:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER    \
    --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --background       \
    --exec /bin/bash -- -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS > /var/log/some.log 2>&1"
```

Also if you use `--chuid` or `--user`, make sure the user can write to `/var/log` or the existing `/var/log/some.log`. The best way is to have that user own a `/var/log/subdir/` though.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you ypocat. Today, as well as saving the log, I needed to run a non-binary script which --exec does not allow but your trick works around!

Comment: The down side ... stopping the service kills bash, but not the child process bash started!  (In my case, DAEMON=coffee).

Comment: I worked around that by killing all child processes of the bash process at the top of do_stop.  `bashPID=$(cat $PIDFILE); [ -n "$bashPID" ] && pkill -P "$bashPID"`

Comment: I used touch and chown in the initscript, to ensure the process will be able to write to the logfile.

Comment: Good to know, and the `pkill` solution too. Wondering what would `... -c "exec $DAEMON..."` (adding the "exec") do. Don't have this on the plate right now so can't try it.

Comment: Btw. in my case the original works OK, I'm using to start/stop elasticsearch with it (a java app). I guess it depends how the app is handling signals.

Comment: @ypocat I just verified that it works with -c "exec $DAEMON...".  This means no pkill hacks required.

Comment: Using this method, will bash always keep the file descriptor for the log file open?  Will this work with logrotate and/or is there any way to keep the log file from growing forever without restarting the daemon?

Comment: @Brian, I think if you need log rotation, you be better off piping the output to syslog or some other daemon that will handle that for you.

Comment: @Harvey, sure, but I don't always want to syslog... I might want a separate log file containing just the output of one service in a location of my choosing.

Comment: @Brian, there are syslogs that can do this for you (divert different incoming log messages to different files). I think there are also some logging utilities that do this as well where you pipe your output to the utility and it will rotate, etc. like syslog.

Comment: @ypocat, be careful if you use a named pipe instead of a logfile. I used that trick to do `mkfifo pipe; logger < pipe &; start-stop... sh... -c "exec ... > pipe 2>&1"; rm pipe`. It's a nice trick, but I found that the `rm pipe` will on some systems execute before the executed daemon opens the pipe. So a slight delay is required. I can't find the other question I got the pipe idea from, but that combined with your answer helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian You can rotate the log using logrotated's `copytruncate` option to empty the file.  This is not atomic, so carries a small risk of losing some log lines.

Comment: I think the answer of @stormbeta is a better approach. Even if this might work in some situation, the approach of ypocat never worked for me in any case.

Answer (score 41):

It seems you should be able to use now the `--no-close` parameter when starting `start-stop-daemon` to capture the daemon output. This [new feature](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=627333) is available in the `dpkg` package since version 1.16.5 on Debian:

> Add new --no-close option to disable closing fds on --background.
>
> This enabled the caller to see process messages for debugging
>   purposes, or to be able to redirect file descriptors to log files,
>   syslog or similar.

Comment: It's a shame it's not available in Ubuntu 12.04 :(

Comment: I can't seem to get that --no-close to work... the output is still going to the shell that i'm executing the init.d script from :(

Comment: +1 Works perfectly on Debian squeeze with a daemonized node.js service.

Comment: @stantonk Did you also pipe stdout/stderr to a file? The complete command line looks like follows. And make sure that the logfile can be written by user $USER:

start-stop-daemon --start --chuid $USER --pidfile $PIDFILE --background --no-close --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMONARGS >> /var/log/xxxxx.log 2>&1

Comment: This is not available with the openrc `start-stop-daemon`.
However the openrc version has the `-1` and `-2` options to redirect the stdout and stderr respectively.

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

With openrc (which is the default on gentoo or alpine linux for instance) `start-stop-daemon` has the `-1` and `-2` options:

> -1, --stdout                 Redirect stdout to file
>
> -2, --stderr                 Redirect stderr to file

So you can just write:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER    \
    --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --background       \
    --exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -1 $LOGFILE -2 $LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 10):

It is not too hard to capture daemon's output and save it to file:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background \
  --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
  --chuid $DAEMON_USER \
  --startas $DAEMON --no-close \
  -- $DAEMON_ARGS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

However this solution may be suboptimal for `logrotate`.

It might be better to capture output to syslog. On [Debian](http://debian.org) this would match behaviour of systemd services.
The following straightforward attempt to rewrite the above example is **wrong** because it leaves behind two parent-less ("zombie") processes (logger and daemon) after stopping the daemon because `start-stop-daemon` terminates only its child but not all descendants:

```
## Do not use this!
start-stop-daemon --start --background \
  --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
  --chuid $DAEMON_USER \
  --startas /bin/sh \
  -- -c """exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS | /usr/bin/logger --tag $NAME"""
```

To make it work we need a wrapper that terminates its children upon receiving `SIGTERM` from `start-stop-daemon`. There are some:

[duende](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/duende):

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background \
  --pidfile $PIDFILE \
  --startas /usr/sbin/duende \
  -- --pid $PIDFILE --chroot=/ --uid 65534 --ident $NAME \
  /bin/su --login $DAEMON_USER --shell /bin/sh --command """exec ${DAEMON} $DAEMON_ARGS"""
```

Note: `uid=65534` is a user `nobody`.

*Pros*: it works and it is relatively easy.
*Cons*: 4 processes (supervisor `duende`, its fork with dropped privileges (logger), `su` and daemon itself); mandatory `--chroot`;
If daemon terminates right away (e.g. invalid command) `status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" "$NAME"` report it as started successfully.

[daemon](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/daemon):

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE \
  --startas /usr/bin/daemon \
  -- --noconfig --name $NAME --stderr=syslog.info --stdout=syslog.info \
  -- /bin/su --login $DAEMON_USER --shell /bin/sh --command """exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS"""
```

*Pros*: 3 processes (supervisor `daemon`, `su` and daemon itself).
*Cons*: Difficult to manage `$PIDFILE` due to confusing *daemon*'s command line options;
If daemon terminates right away (e.g. invalid command) `status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" "$NAME"` report it as started successfully.

#### [pipexec](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/pipexec) (*the winner*):

```
start-stop-daemon --start --background \
  --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
  --chuid $DAEMON_USER \
  --startas /usr/bin/pipexec -- -k \
   -- [ D $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS ] [ L /usr/bin/logger --tag $NAME ] '{D:2>D:1}' '{D:1>L:0}'
```

*Pros*: 3 processes (supervisor `pipexec`, `logger` and daemon itself); If daemon terminates right away (e.g. invalid command) `status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" "$NAME"` correctly report failure.
*Cons*: none.

This is the winner -- the easiest, neat solution that seems to be working well.

Comment: To use a separate file to log into, see Ansgar Wiechers answer under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045946/write-to-custom-log-file-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 8):

Usually `start-stop-daemon` closes the standard file descriptors when running in the background. 
From the man page of `start-stop-daemon`:

> -C, --no-close
>    Do  not  close  any file descriptor when forcing the daemon into the background.  Used for debugging purposes to see the
>                 process output, or to redirect file descriptors to log the process output.  Only relevant when using --background.

This one worked for me:

```
    start-stop-daemon -b -C -o -c \ 
         $DAEMON_USER -S -x $DAEMON > $DAEMON_LOG 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting an old mailing list:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-uk/2005-June/000037.html

> An easy -- and if you want to use start-stop-daemon perhaps the only -- way
>   around it is to create a small script containing:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> exec /home/boinc/boinc/boinc > /home/boinc/log/boinc.log
> ```
>
> and then use that script as the argument to start-stop-daemon.
>
> Perhaps the real question however is whether it is really necessary to use
>   start-stop-daemon in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS > /var/log/some.log 2>&1" will ever close the file descriptor for the log file...  which means if your daemon runs forever, I'm not sure that logrotate or other mechanisms for cleaning up disk space would work.  Since it's > instead of >>, the suggested command would also truncate existing logs on restart.  If you want to see why the daemon crashed, and it restarts automatically, that might not be very helpful.

Another option might be "$DAEMON | logger". logger is a command that will log to syslog (/var/log/messages).  If you need stderr too, I think you could use "$DAEMON 1>&2 | logger"

Comment: You are correct, using `>>` is generally more appropriate for daemons, although it implies you should now create a logrotate rule!

Comment: As for disk-space, methods which **truncate** the file will get the space back immediately (at least under ext filesystems).  But beware methods which simply **delete** a file which is still being written to: the space will not be reclaimed until the handle is released, and you can no longer find the file node to manually truncate it!

Comment: @joeytwiddle 
part of my point here is that there are situations where logrotate will fail to rotate logs if the file handle is never closed.

Comment: `--no-close ... | logger` does not work for me (Debian 7.3, start-stop-daemon 1.16.12). The start-stop-daemon script doesn't come back, though /var/log/messages is filled :-). I tried it with and without `1>&2`.

Comment: hgoebl you need to have the "cmd | logger" expression in quotes, so the interpreter will know it's "cmd" you are piping to logger, not the start-stop-daemon expression.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's bash (although some other shells may allow this as well), the line:

```
exec >>/tmp/myDaemon.log
```

will send all future standard output to that file. That's because `exec` without a program name just does some redirection magic. From the `bash` man page:

> If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell.

Management of said file is another issue of course.

Comment: can you clarify where this line is supposed to be placed? Right after the `start-stop-daemon` line which the initial question mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

there is an option `--no-close` for `start-stop-daemon`, which means "don't close any fd when it's run background."

```sh
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER    \
    --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --background       \
    --exec $DAEMON --no-close \
    -- $DAEMON_ARGS > /var/log/some.log 2>&1
```

this redirect the stdout/stderr of process `start-stop-daemon` to the file. and your executable inherits stdout/stderr from its parent process `start-stop-daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sudo -u myuser -i start-stop-daemon ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.20 there is an option --output for doing exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

With modern start-stop-daemon it is enough to use:

```
--background --output /path/to/the/file
```