# How can I redirect process output from a process started with start-stop-daemon on Debian?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, debian, start-stop-daemon

There are several questions about this already but none of them seem to work.  I have a production system that is currently down and I need to be able to get the stderr output from the daemon quickly to debug it.

I thought I could just redirect the output from the point it is called (in an init.d script) but it is proving extremely difficult.

```
 start-stop-daemon -d $DDIR -b -m --start --quiet -pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS > /var/log/daemon.log 2>&1 \
                || return 2
```

This does not work.  I tried running a shell script that calls the executable and redirects the output but still the log file remained empty (and I do know that the process is outputting information).

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can't you improve the source code of your daemon to use `syslog(3)` facilities? AFAIK `start-stop-daemon` is like `daemon(3)` with `noclose=0` so closes `stdout` & `stderr` (redirecting them to `/dev/null`)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251933/how-can-i-log-the-stdout-of-a-process-started-by-start-stop-daemon/33606496#33606496) seems to work...

Answer (score 4):

If you have start-stop-daemon >= version 1.16.5 you simply call it with `--no-close` to be able to redirect the output of the *started* process.

From `man start-stop-daemon`:

> -C, --no-close
>
> ```
>           Do not close any file descriptor when forcing the daemon into
>           the background (since version 1.16.5).  Used for debugging
>           purposes to see the process output, or to redirect file
>           descriptors to log the process output.  Only relevant when
>           using --background.
> ```

Comment: That was the solution I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i remember, this is impossible, usually when i need to get data from a daemon process i either log it before hand or create a monitor program that connects to the program via network sockets or named pipes or any other interprocess communication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Calling *start-stop-daemon* with `> /var/log/daemon.log 2>&1` will redirect *start-stop-daemon*'s output and **not the started daemon's output**. *Start-stop-daemon* will close standard output/input descriptors before running a daemon.

Wrapping an executable in a simple shell script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
STDERR=$1
shift
DAEMON=$1
shift
$DAEMON 2>$STDERR $*
```

works for me - maybe you should check file permissions?

There is a problem with this naive solution - when *start-stop-daemon* kills this wrapper, the wrapped daemon will be left alive. That cannot be easily solved in bash, because you cannot run signal handlers during the script execution (see `trap` documentation for details). You have to write a C wrapper which looks like that:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int fd_err;

    fd_err = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    dup2(fd_err, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(fd_err);

    return execvp(argv[2], argv + 2);
}
```

(I've omitted error checking for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that may work (based on the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself)).

At the beginning of your init.d script (and after the header), add the following:

```
exec > >(tee --append /var/log/daemon.log)

#You may also choose to log to /var/log/messages using this:
#exec > >(logger -t MY_DAEMON_NAME)

#And redirect errors to the same file with this:
exec 2>&1
```

This will log all that is invoked during your script, including `start-stop-daemon` output.