# Logging TCP socket events

Tags: python, file, sockets, logging

Currently, I've got a tcp socket running, I was thinking on adding the capability for the server side to write to a log file, what has been sent/received/errors over the socket. My server script is running as a service on boot.

I'm wondering if its possible to do it? I've looked up the logging facilities on the python docs, but it doesn't seem to have much details on it(or I just can't understand). I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Using the logging python class to write to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/using-the-logging-python-class-to-write-to-a-file)

If you do not want to use the logging class, you could simply open a file and write error messages to it.

Another option if on Linux is doing something like this:
[How can I log the stdout of a process started by start-stop-daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251933/how-can-i-log-the-stdout-of-a-process-started-by-start-stop-daemon)

Answer (score 2):

Tried netcat?

e.g.

```
netcat -l 0.0.0.0 1999 |tee /tmp/log.txt
```

This opens a listening TCP socket on port 1999 on your host open to the world. It then will write a copy of anything incoming to `/tmp/log.txt`.